# Value Calculation on oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    TITLE  VARCHAR2(199 BYTE),
    AMOUNT NUMBER,
    VALUE  NUMBER
)
```

and this `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (TITLE, AMOUNT, VAL) 
VALUES (Switch, 3000, 12); 
COMMIT;
```

We have an amount = 3000 up to 12, now we need to calculate.

So

- 3000 multiplied by 1 = 3000
- 3000 multiplied by 2 = 6000
- 3000 multiplied by 3 = 9000
- 3000 multiplied by 4 = 12000
- 3000 multiplied by 5 = 15000
- 3000 multiplied by 6 = 18000
- 3000 multiplied by 7 = 21000
- 3000 multiplied by 8 = 24000
- 3000 multiplied by 9 = 27000
- 3000 multiplied by 10 = 30000
- 3000 multiplied by 11 = 33000
- 3000 multiplied by 12 = 36000

Regards

Output is needed in the following format.

```
Title    Amount                                                     Total

Switch   30000  3000 6000 9000  12000 15000 18000 21000 24000 27000 30000 33000 36000   231000
plug
board
```

Can somebody help me how to get this output in SQL?

Comment: Please show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query:

```
WITH data (title, amount, value, idx) AS (
  SELECT title, amount, value, 1
  FROM test
UNION ALL
  SELECT title, amount, value, idx + 1
  FROM   data
  WHERE  idx < value
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY title SET order_num
SELECT title, amount * idx AS value
FROM   data;
```

Or a correlated hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT t.title, t.amount * l.idx AS value
FROM   test t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS idx FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.value
       ) l;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST ( TITLE VARCHAR2(199 BYTE), AMOUNT NUMBER, VALUE NUMBER )
INSERT INTO TEST ( TITLE, AMOUNT, VALUE ) VALUES ( 'Switch', 3000, 12);
```

Both output:

| TITLE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| Switch | 3000 |
| Switch | 6000 |
| Switch | 9000 |
| Switch | 12000 |
| Switch | 15000 |
| Switch | 18000 |
| Switch | 21000 |
| Switch | 24000 |
| Switch | 27000 |
| Switch | 30000 |
| Switch | 33000 |
| Switch | 36000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KbHwbP4D)

---

Or for your output format:

```sql
WITH data (title, amount, value, idx) AS (
  SELECT title, amount, value, 1
  FROM test
UNION ALL
  SELECT title, amount, value, idx + 1
  FROM   data
  WHERE  idx < value
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY title SET order_num
SELECT title,
       LISTAGG(amount * idx, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY idx) AS amounts,
       SUM(amount*idx) AS total
FROM   data
GROUP BY title;
```

or

```sql
SELECT t.title,
       l.amounts,
       t.amount * t.value * (t.value + 1) / 2 AS total
FROM   test t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(LEVEL * t.amount, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL) AS amounts
         FROM   DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.value
       ) l;
```

Which both output:

| TITLE | AMOUNTS | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Switch | 3000 6000 9000 12000 15000 18000 21000 24000 27000 30000 33000 36000 | 234000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P1Um4YML)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like here:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 'Switch' "TITLE", 3000 "AMOUNT", 12 "VAL" From Dual
        )
--
Select     TITLE, AMOUNT, TOTAL
From      (Select LEVEL "ID", TITLE "TITLE", Sum(AMOUNT * LEVEL) OVER() "TOTAL",
                  LISTAGG(AMOUNT * LEVEL, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL) OVER() "AMOUNT"
          From    tbl
          Connect By LEVEL <= VAL )
Where ID = 1  
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--  TITLE   AMOUNT                                                                 TOTAL
--  ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------- ------
--  Switch  3000 6000 9000 12000 15000 18000 21000 24000 27000 30000 33000 36000    234000
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear Respectful Experts
Thanks for your Cooperation,
I have oracle 10 G which do not support LISTAGG, what i need to do in 10G,

Thanks

Regards